# python2 -m pip freeze showing an error

Tags: python, pip

I get an error when I execute `python2 -m pip freeze` this command. 
The error message is as below:

`/usr/bin/python: cannot import name HashMissing; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

I had used `apt-get remove --purge python python-pip` fo removing the python2.

Then, I do these path checking for knowing pip and python command path.

```
    john@mymachine:~$ whereis python
    python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/lib/python3.4     /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.4 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
    john@mymachine:~$ which -a pip
    /usr/local/bin/pip
    jonh@mymachine:~$ whereis pip
    pip: /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.5 /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip3.4
    john@mymachine:~$ which -a python
    /usr/bin/python
```

Wish some help.

Comment: just use `pip freeze`

Comment: Not work. The message is same.

Comment: according to the post above you've uninstalled pip, have you reinstalled it again? and are you sure the error is "the same"

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri Yes. Wether I use pip or python -m pip, it show the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the reason. But, I install the pip again.

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
and
`python get-pip.py`

The problem is resolved.